# How do I list the databases from a differnet version of PostgreSQL using psql.exe on windows?

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line-interface, psql

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this correctly, but I'm trying to view the databases under PostgreSQL 16 via command line, however they don't show up for me.

Is there a flag I need to set to specify the databases from PostgreSQL 16?

[image]

Comment: That's a different cluster/instance, probably running on a different port. If you have access to it in pgAdmin, check what port it's on and give that to psql, replacing the default 5432: `./psql.exe -U postgres -p 5432`.

Comment: I'm new to PostgreSQL, but both 15 and 16 are installed locally on my workstation, however likely on different ports. How can I connect using a different port?

Comment: Open task manager and look for tasks with a name starting with "pg" and inspect their details to find their version (look at the path) and port

Comment: @level42 [Right-click "PostgreSQL 16" in pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/server_dialog.html#server-dialog) and check the connection info. Then [`./psql.exe -p <port> -h <hostname> postgres`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-OPTION-FIELD-HOST)

Comment: I think I've got it! I didn't realize that they were using different ports. It seems I can specify the `-p 5433` flag to specify the port of PostgreSQL 16! Now I just need to figure out how to reset the password for the `postgres` user account and I should be all set!

Comment: Thank you @Zegarek!!! this was exactly the information I was looking for! Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Offtopic: I use the version number as port number to make it easier to remember: 54315 for version 15 and 54316 for version 16.